# How to set corner radius of a view inside a view in tableview cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am new to iOS and I stucked in this issue. I am creating a custom cell like this[image: UITableviewcell]

I have taken a rectangular view(on left) inside main view. Here is the code for setting a corner radius of both views.

```
_viewBG.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
_viewBG.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
_viewBG.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
_viewBG.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
_viewBG.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath
                          bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.viewLeft.bounds
                          byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft)
                          cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10, 10)
                          ];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

self.viewLeft.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

But I am getting this output..

[image]

So I want to set the corner radius of red color uiview as per the main view... Any idea would be appreciated. Can you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

steps:

1. make a main wrapper view which holds your left and right view.. set its background color to clear color..
2. inside main wrapper view  add another view and give  it corner radius as desired and mask to bound true
3. inside this subview made in step 2 add your red and another view with property clip to bounds true
4. now in main wrapperview give your shadow and mask to bound set false

Comment: Ok, I will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Elegant solution.. Thanks, Ashwin Sir!

Comment: always a pleasure.. to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set `clipToBounds = true` of cell.

in your case it will be `_viewBG.clipToBounds = true`

To make shadow visible use `_viewBG.layer.maskToBounds = false`

Comment: But with your solution, shadow around main view is lost... Any guesses why?

Comment: If it solves your problem then accept this answer so it become helpful to other people also...:)

Comment: It doesn't solved. When I set _viewBG.layer.maskToBounds = false, it appears the shadow but with  my old output.  :(